# What do the colored bubbles mean in hierarchy viewer?

Tags: android

[image]

I am guessing they are a quick overview of the time it took to draw the view, but I am not positive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

they are an indication of the time it took to (from left to right) measure, layout and draw; green being good, red being bad. In measuring and layout red blobs usually occur when the hierarchy is very deep, or you have a lot of views in general (say more than 100ish).

Answer (score 0):

I would add that a green bubble doesn't mean it's 100% good and a red one doesn't mean that this view is bad. Green/Yellow/Red show how well does this `View` (or `ViewGroup`) behaves comparing to its siblings.

Here is an example: `AppcompatCheckedTextView` takes reasonable half of millisecond here, considering the fact it contains both text and image. It is red just because the other sibling view is super simple.

[image: /Users/gaket/Pictures/Screenshots/Снимок экрана 2018-02-03 в 20.02.21.png]

In the same time, the screen has another view with green bubbles that gets all the 16msec in which the whole frame should be rendered ([Why 60 fps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render.html)), what is bad. But because there is an even slower sibling, the tool shows it with green markers:

[image]